# Como listar dados de JSON em uma div usando jquery?

Tags: jquery, json

Amigos, tenho o seguinte JSON:

```
{
"codigo": "12345",
"cerca": "Rato",
"host": "df",
"eventos": [
    {
        "data": "21\/02\/2020",
        "hora": "19:38",
        "local": "Moema\/SP",
        "status": "Morto",
        "subTim": [
            "Um dia sem PC"
        ]
    },
    {
        "data": "21\/02\/2020",
        "hora": "18:29",
        "local": "Tatuapé\/SP",
        "status": "Meio vivo",
        "subTim": [
            "Quatro dias sem PC"
        ]
    },
    {
        "data": "21\/02\/2020",
        "hora": "18:09",
        "local": "Anápolis\/GO",
        "status": "Só tonto",
        "subTim": [
            "Dois dias sem PC"
        ]
    }
]}
```

Consigo carregar no form corretamente alguns dados do JSON assim com JS:

```
jQuery("#codigo").val(resposta.codigo);
jQuery("#cerca").val(resposta.cerca);
jQuery("#host").val(resposta.host);
```

Qual a maneira correta jquery de listar os "eventos", com "data", "status" e "subTim" em uma div de nome #ocorridos no form ? Exemplo:

Ocorridos: Meu código: 12345 / Cerca: Rato / Host: df

---

Evento1: 21/02/2020 19:38 / Status: Morto / SubTim: Um dia sem PC

---

Evento2: 21/02/2020 18:29 / Status: Meio vivo / SubTim: Quatro dias sem PC

---

Evento3: 21/02/2020 18:09 / Status: Só tonto / SubTim: Dois dias sem PC

Desde já muito obrigada pela atenção de vocês

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colega, o código está meio engessado. Dá pra fazer melhor (mais dinâmico). Mas dá uma olhada e vê se te atende. Qualquer dúvida, você avisa no comentário, que eu tento melhorar algo. Você poderia adaptar melhor de acordo com sua necessidade. Essa resposta foi só pra te dar uma ideia de onde partir.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" id="teste">
    <div class="">
      <h5 id="h5-teste"></h5>
      <p id="p-teste-1"></p>
      <p id="p-teste-2"></p>
      <p id="p-teste-3"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    let json = {
      "codigo": "12345",
      "cerca": "Rato",
      "host": "df",
      "eventos": [{
          "data": "21\/02\/2020",
          "hora": "19:38",
          "local": "Moema\/SP",
          "status": "Morto",
          "subTim": [
            "Um dia sem PC"
          ]
        },
        {
          "data": "21\/02\/2020",
          "hora": "18:29",
          "local": "Tatuapé\/SP",
          "status": "Meio vivo",
          "subTim": [
            "Quatro dias sem PC"
          ]
        },
        {
          "data": "21\/02\/2020",
          "hora": "18:09",
          "local": "Anápolis\/GO",
          "status": "Só tonto",
          "subTim": [
            "Dois dias sem PC"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }

    let codigo;
    let rato;
    let host;

    let evento_1;
    let evento_2;
    let evento_3;

    $.each(json, function(index, value) {
      if (index == "codigo") {
        codigo = "Ocorridos: Meu código: " + value + " / ";
      }
      if (index == "cerca") {
        rato = "Rato: " + value + " / ";
      }
      if (index == "host") {
        host = "Host: " + value;
      }

      if (index == "eventos") {

        $.each(value, function(chave, valor) {
          if (chave == 0) {
            evento_1 = "Evento 1: " + valor.data + " " + valor.hora + " / Status: " + valor.status + " / SubTim: " + valor.subTim[0];
          }
          if (chave == 1) {
            evento_2 = "Evento 2: " + valor.data + " " + valor.hora + " / Status: " + valor.status + " / SubTim: " + valor.subTim[0];
          }
          if (chave == 2) {
            evento_3 = "Evento 3: " + valor.data + " " + valor.hora + " / Status: " + valor.status + " / SubTim: " + valor.subTim[0];
          }
        });
      }
    });

    codigo += rato;
    codigo += host;

    $("#h5-teste").html(codigo);
    $("#p-teste-1").html(evento_1);
    $("#p-teste-2").html(evento_2);
    $("#p-teste-3").html(evento_3);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

- Utilizei jQuery (como você solicitou) e Bootstrap (só usei para dar uma alinhada ali, por preguiça de fazer em CSS, rs). Espero que sirva pra você.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente Gambi, minha ultima dúvida sobre: Como fica ao invés do let json, carregar esses mesmos dados json de uma url externa? let url = "https://.... ? a estrutura da resposta da url remota é a mesma.

Comment: @AnaCavalcante , não deu pra responder antes, pois eu estava com a conta bloqueada pelo absurdo motivo de manipulação de votos. Mas você já conseguiu resolver seu problema ? Dá pra fazer essa sua situação com Ajax.

Comment: Deu certinho @Gambi, sua resposta foi de grande ajuda. Obrigada.